# Observable pattern in Remote EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, observable, payara

I have 2 applications. One 'main' and a second one with a Remote EJB. The first application calls the Remote EJB in the second one.

Now I want to implement the Observable pattern. But it doesn't seem to work cross-application.

So I want my Observable inside the second application, and my Observers in the first. When I try it, it doesn't seem to work. It only works if I make the Observable and Observers in the same application.

I got another solution, but I think it's dirty. I could use a MDB inside the second application, and publish a message on a Topic, and then consume those messages inside the first application. But then again, that seems kinda dirty.

I'm using JEE7 on a Payara 4.1.1.171 server.

**Edit**:
Because I figured out that triggered Events don't exit an EAR file, I'm now using the MDB method. But that still does not work.
More information, this is the package structure of the EAR file.

```
my-application.ear
+--- common-ejb.jar (EJB)
|       +--- MessageDrivenBean.java (Triggers the event)
+--- my-application.jar (EJB)
+--- my-application.war (WEB)
        +--- WEB-INF
                +--- lib
                |       +--- common-web.jar (Resources WEB jar)
                |           +--- SessionBean1 to receive the events
                +--- classes
                        +--- SessionBean2 to receive the events
```

As you can see there are 2 session beans to receive the events, but none of the 2 actually receive them.

Comment: Don't know much about what you are trying to achieve, but have you tried to look to the MBean world ?

Comment: Using JMS in this way is a perfectly reasonable solution. If you ensure that your events are serializable then you could conceivably use a JMS queue instead and use it build an "Event Bridge" between applications.

Comment: Using JMS does work partially. But now I have the MDB processing the "trigger-message" and would like to trigger all session beans that are alive (ignoring their session). But for some reason, I need to use an ApplicationScoped bean between the MDB and the SessionScoped beans.

Comment: Isn't there an option where I don't need to use the ApplicationScoped bean, but just fire a trigger inside the MDB and listen to these triggers in all of the beans, ignoring their state.

Comment: Exactly how are your session beans annotated?

Comment: All of them have `@Named`, and some have `@SessionScoped`, others `@ViewScoped`

Comment: HAve you looked into using Google's EventBus?

Answer (score 0):

Given a message driven bean:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/queue/SampleQueue")
})
public class EventListener implements MessageListener {

    @Inject
    @Any
    Event<MyEvent> loggedInEvent;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            try {
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
                loggedInEvent.fire(((MyEvent) objectMessage.getObject()));
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where MyEvent is a simple POJO:

```
public class MyEvent implements Serializable {

    private final String payload; 

    public MyEvent(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

then this @SessionScoped bean:

```
@SessionScoped
public class EventHandler {

    public void handleEvent(@Observes MyEvent myEvent) {
        System.out.println(myEvent.getPayload());
    }
}
```

prints the payload String when a `MyEvent` object is sent to the queue associated with the `EventListener`

Any number of observers can be provided.

Comment: I've tried this but it does not work. The events just aren't triggered where I need them to be triggered. I have logging in each method (the Observable method, but also in both Observe methods). Only the fire is logged. I have set my ear structure in the question itself.

Comment: Put everything in the WAR file and it should work. The problem you have now is that classes in the EAR (EJBs and lib dir) cannot see the classes in the WAR file. Don't build EARs anymore unless you need to (because of multiple WARs in it mainly).

Comment: Mind you, @OndrejM 's answer looks pretty cool - but it's not portable

Answer (score 0):

With Payara Server version 171 and Hazelcast enabled, you can fire CDI events and observe them in another application. See the documentation about [remote CDI events](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/cdi-events.html)

If both applications are deployed on the same Payara Server instance, you would fire an event of type MyEvent.class like this:

```
@Inject
@Outbound(loopBack = true) // loopBack true is required if the observing application is deployed on the same Payara Server instance
Event<MyEvent> event;

...
event.fire(new MyEvent());
```

And the other application would observe these events with:

```
public void receiveEvent(@Observes @Inbound MyEvent event) {
}
```

If the observing application is running on another Payara Server instance in the same Hazelcast cluster, it would also receive the event. In that case, loopBack attribute is not required, but would do no harm either.

Remote CDI events are dispatched via embedded Hazelcast data grid, which will reliably deliver the events to all observing applications across the cluster. The observing application has to be running at the time when the event is fire - a similar behavior to broadcasting events via a JMS topic.

Comment: This works more than what I had before, but now I'm getting ClassCastExceptions on Hazelcast. More specific `org.glassfish.api.invocation.ComponentInvocation cannot be cast to com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation`. Which is thrown from `com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:171)`. I've tried upgrading to Payara 171.1 because in the release notes is something about ClassCastExceptions with Remote EJB's (which I'm using), but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: If you cannot find an error in your application, you should raise an issue on Payara GitHub, with as much info as possible, including complete stacktrace.