# Event not working in Message Driven Bean

Tags: events, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm trying to generate and handle an event when my MDB receives a message. Here is what I'm doing:

```
public class MDBBooks implements MessageListener {
@Inject 
private Event<Update> messageReceived;

public MDBLibri() {
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Message received");
    try {
        Update u = message.getBody(Update.class);
        messageReceived.fire(u);
        if(u != null){
            ... stuff        
        }
    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        System.out.println("JMSException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public void eventHandler(@Observes Update up) {
    System.out.println("There was an update");
}

}
```

But it just does not work, the string "There was an update" it's not printed in the glassfish console. I can't really tell what's the problem, my textbook does it the same way pretty much. I'm assuming the event fires fine, but the event handler isn't notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the **observer method does not get notified**. In fact, CDI doesn't even know it exists. The reason is that in CDI, message-driven beans are non-contextual objects. To simplify, they are not considered CDI beans, but you can still inject into them and intercept them.

Now, **for CDI to recognize an observer method, you have to place it in a managed bean or a session bean**. Quoting the spec:

> An observer method is a non-abstract method of a managed bean class or session bean class (or of an extension, as defined in Container lifecycle events).

So a solution for you would be to place your observer method in another class, which is either a managed bean or a session bean.

Comment: There is a similar answer (with implementation) in [an otherwise unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111276/observable-pattern-in-remote-ejb/43120204#43120204)

Comment: Well ... the whole "implementation" the OP needs here, is to move the observer method to a different class.

Comment: Indeed, my comment was only intended as something for the OP to look at (I probably could have worded it better). Your answer is quite correct and I had up-voted it accordingly

Comment: Thank you, somehow I missed that MDBs are not considered CDI beans.